# Problems with Jackrabbit XPath Query with an OR statement

Tags: xpath, jackrabbit

I have the following Xpath Query in my Jackrabbit 2.2 application:

```
//crms:publications/*/*[
   @crms:publication-security = '28862' OR 
   @crms:publication-security='23459' OR 
   @crms:publication-security='23489'
]
```

which is causing the following exception when it is executed

> `javax.jcr.query.InvalidQueryException:
>   Lexical error at line 1, column 73. 
>   Encountered: "@" (64), after : "" for
>   statement: for $v in
>   //crms:publications/*/*[@crms:publication-security='28862' OR @crms:publication-security='23459'
>   OR @crms:publication-security='23489']
>   return $v`

but if I run the following query without the OR's it runs fine:

```
//crms:publications/*/*[@crms:publication-security='28862']
```

It is probably something obvious but any guidance would be appreciated on what I am doing wrong

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

It was obvious unfortunately. XPath is case sensitive so 'OR' should have been 'or'